# Unable to reference path for a folder of csv files

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1C5Fnf8Rxq8wG2fGakvbWQ9AKu9cLsnr8#scrollTo=DZ7srOAiN1in

Above is the link to my Google Colab notebook.

I have downloaded a folder of multiple csv files that I am trying to reference. Here is my current path:'`drive/MyDrive/FFP_bro'`.

This is the error I am getting: `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'drive/MyDrive/FFP_bro'`

Answer (score 0):

I can't access your notebook but my guess is that the path address is not correct. You might want to show a snippet of your code and your directory architecture to get answers.